# Continue on CLI after executing file

Tags: node.js

Is there anyway to make Nodejs continue to receive input like a general CLI when we called.

`$ nodejs`

For example: I have an index.js file below

```
// index.js
var a = 10
goToCLI()
```

What I expect is when I call `$ nodejs ./index.js` it will appear `a` nodejs cli with a variable already declared. Is it possible? If it is, how?

Comment: Do you mean you want to run a `index.js` using NodeJS and then run the NodeJS REPL with the "closure" (or context) of `index.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the Node.js REPL without your script first. Then, inside the REPL you may load your script.

```
$ node
> .load index.js
// index.js
var a = 10

undefined
> a
10
>
```

Alternatively, you can start up a REPLserver inside your script, along the lines of what your `goToCLI()` implied:

```
const repl = require('repl');

function initializeContext(context) {
    // Initialize the REPL environment here.
    // This is where your variable setup would go for instance:
    context.a = 10;
}

const r = repl.start({ prompt: '> ' });
initializeContext(r.context);

r.on('reset', initializeContext);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`REPL`](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_global_and_local_scope) module. It will include any global variables in the scope, but others you need to add to the context. For example:

```
var repl = require("repl");

b = 20

repl.start("> ").context.a = 10
```

This will start the repl with both `a` and `b` in scope.